# CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation errors

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm using `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` to sync changes in my custom zone. It seemed to be working fine in my development environment, but I'm getting some errors when testing in the Production environment. The localized description of the two errors is below:

> client knowledge differs from server knowledge
>
> Couldn't fetch some items when fetching changes

Any suggestions on what can cause these errors would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

OK. I did some further digging and found the root cause of the error messages. I was printing the error's `localizedDescription` for debugging purposes; however, upon further inspection of the error object, the `ckErrorCode == .changeTokenExpired` which obviously I did not handle properly!

Resetting the change token and retrying `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation()` then yielded the correct results.

I hope this helps somebody!